# remove 'alpha lowered' of disabled uibutton

Tags: button, uibutton, alpha, isenabled

Every time I disable a UIButton. E.g. button1.enabled = NO;
The UIButton sets it's alpha to 0.4 or something.
But I don't want this!
Can I turn this off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by implementing a integer which gives the button permission to perform an action. This is of course not the solution but maybe it can help you too.